# How to Achieve Max Speed Transactions ( Transfers ) between Lora Packet Forwarder to Remote Server

Tags: raspberry-pi, networking, hardware, lorawan, software

I have a Lorawan devices that works as witnesser and beaconer.

Simply it gets the **Signal-Data** from other same type of Lorawan devices.

There is a **Packet Forwarder** software on that device OS and it gets and process that **Signal-Data**.

This **Packet Forwarder** software pushes the data to **Local-Docker**.

That **Local-Docker** reads the i2c-data one time ( placed on Lorawan device board ) and gets its identity and then starts.

Also that **Local-Docker**'s job is getting the processed **Signal-Data** from **Packet Forwarder** and pushes it to **Remote Frankfurt Server** with its ID ( got from i2c )
( It is not my server it is the platform remote server )

There is a race; who sends the fastest **Signal-Data** to Frankfurt platform server gets the reward.
On my country there are lots of redirections caused by IPS while my **Local-Docker** try to send **Signal-Data** to **Remote Frankfurt Server**.

So I hired a vps on Frankfurt from google and all my Lorawan devices uses the VPN via my IPS-modem.
It significantly reduces the delay of data transfer time but still It is not enough for me.
If you have clear suggestions I would like to hear them out.

- Like installing docker directly to remote server - but I don't know how that docker reads the i2c-data from the local device. Without reading i2c-data means no id and it can't be started.

**Here is the flow chart.**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this mean? `fastest Signal-Data`

Comment: Transfer rate of data between 2 locations @jsotola